# When opening files with WinSCP, Atom opens multiple times

Tags: winscp, atom-editor

When I open multiple files with WinSCP Atom opens once for each file which takes a long loading time.

Is there any setting in WinSCP or Atom which changes that behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Atom has command-line switch `-a`, which causes it to open the file in the existing window.

So, in WinSCP, in [external Editor preferences](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_editor_preferences), use this command:

```
"%LOCALAPPDATA%\atom\atom.exe" -a !.!
```

See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration_editor#atom